# Exporting scene in GLTF format from react-three-fiber

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I am trying to save my scene in a GLTF fromat. I saw examples with exports from Three.js by using exportGLTF but I can't figure out how I can do the same thing in react with react-three-fiber meshes. The example I found is: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/misc_exporter_gltf.html.

Comment: there is no difference, you use it in the exact same way. you get the default scene via const { scene } = useThree()

Comment: I don't use vanila THREE.js and I don't have const { scene } = useThree(), instead I have <mesh> inside <Canvas> from react-three-fiber.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to get a ref from the  component and use it in some react state callback like useEffect something like this

```
export default function something(props){
 const meshRef = useRef();
 const exporter = new GLTFExporter();

 useEffect(() =>{
  exporter.parse( meshRef.current, function ( gltf ) {
    downloadJSON( gltf );
  }, options ); // you will have to provide the options here
 })
 return(
  <mesh ref={meshRef}>
  ...
  </mesh>
 )
}
```